# PHP Javascript - Insert variable into total parameter of PayPal checkout

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, api, paypal

I have this code here to checkout on a website:

```
<div id="paypal-button"></div>

    <script>
        paypal.Button.render({

            env: 'sandbox',

            client: {
                sandbox:    'XXXXXX',
                production: 'XXXXXX'
            },

            commit: true,

            payment: function(data, actions) {
                return actions.payment.create({
                    payment: {
                        transactions: [
                            {
                                amount: { total: '14.50', currency: 'GBP' }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                });
            },

            onAuthorize: function(data, actions) {
                return actions.payment.execute().then(function(payment) {

                });
            }

        }, '#paypal-button');
    </script>
```

Instead of having the price set to '14.50', I want this value to be the value of the cart. So for example, if the cart total comes to '30.50', I want this value to be '30.50'. I know that you cannot just insert a variable into the Javascript though.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What exactly do you mean when you say that you cannot insert a variable in Javascript?

Do you display the cart total somewhere? You could use something like this get the value from the DOM and update your script:

```
var cartTotal = document.getElementById('yourCartTotalInputHere').value;
```

And replace the amount '14.50' with the variable `cartTotal`.

Alternatively, if you have a Javascript class managing your cart you can save the value in a namespace in the global window and you can access it that way. Example:

```
window.cartData.amount = 30;
```

Then replace '14.50' with `window.cartData.amount`.

Comment: I added this: var subtotal = "<?php echo $cart->total_cost(); ?>"; and then tried to replace the '14.50' with subtotal, but it doesnt seem to work

Comment: @JaidanBrown That is PHP, not Javascript. PHP is being evaluated only when you are rendering your document. You need to use Javascript to update the cart value on client side.